# SQL getting the closest date grouped by

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to make a select and and get the last inserted row, I am using the SYSTEM_CREATE_DATE column to track the last one.

So I execute the follow query:

```
SELECT * FROM tcp_message GROUP BY imei ORDER BY create_date DESC;
```

But I am not getting the last row but the first.

Am I missing something?

Comment: It's not clear why you are using a GROUP BY here. What are you trying to do with that?

Comment: I'm assuming you want the last inserted row for each distinct IMEI ordered by create_date? Your GROUP BY is likely collapsing all of the entries for IMEI and giving you the oldest date, and not the most recent.

Comment: You're retrieving all the rows so the row that that is returned last is the first inserted row. If you want the last row try using SELECT TOP 1 * FROM tcp_message ...